# how to fix arguments '{'pk'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$'] in PostDetailView

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I use slug in the post url, but when sending a post update I get an error

I have this error in views.py **return super().form_valid(form)**

> Reverse for 'postdetail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P[^/]+)/$']

## models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    first_image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='post_image')
    content = RichTextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('postdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def post_slug(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug =  unique_slug_generator(instance)


pre_save.connect(post_slug, sender=Post)
```

## views.py

```
.........

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'first_image', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    UserPostListView
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
......

    path('post/<slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='postupdate'),
    path('post/<slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='postdetail'),

......
]
```

Comment: add `PostDetailView` in question

Comment: I am pretty sure `post/<slug>/` is wrong. I think you want `post/(?P<slug>)/`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: well you're probably doing something else wrong then.

Comment: @RedCricket `post/<slug>/` is also correct. This is Django's new url pattern syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `postdetail` url only accepts the argument named `slug`. While you're passing it `pk`. Obviously it will fail.

Change this:

```
return reverse('postdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

to this:

```
return reverse('postdetail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```